# Node-sass throws error while installing

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, frontend, node-sass

This is the complete log:

```
r2d2@r2d2-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/Insta$ sudo npm install node-sass --save-dev

> node-sass@4.8.3 install /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.8.3 postinstall /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/bin/node /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.10.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.12\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.10.0
gyp verb command install [ '8.10.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.10.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.10.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.10.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN instagram@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.8.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.8.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/r2d2/.npm/_logs/2018-04-13T03_54_45_281Z-debug.log
```

Also, some forums stated that creating a symlink with the command provided below would solve the issue. But it says that file already exists.

```
r2d2@r2d2-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists
r2d2@r2d2-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/nodejs': File exists
```

Docs for node sass mention this but I cannot find relevant information:

Some users have reported issues installing on Ubuntu due to node being registered to another package. Follow the official NodeJS docs to install NodeJS so that #!/usr/bin/env node correctly resolves.

How can I solve this issue? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have node v8.10.0

Comment: `sudo` should be unnecessary if the goal is to install this node module as a dev dependency locally within a project. Generally, one will run `sudo` while installing a package globally on their system (`npm install -g <PACKAGE_NAME>`).

Comment: If I do not type sudo, it says operating system rejected the operation and throws error.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/` and `/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/node_modules`? (Can be found via `stat <DIRECTORY>`)

Also, have you tried deleting `node_modules` and then running `npm install` again? This tends to fix many permission issues with npm.

Comment: This is what i get
  r2d2@r2d2-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/Insta$ stat 
  /home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/
  File: '/home/r2d2/Desktop/Practice/Insta/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directoryDevice: 805h/2053d      Inode: 13501599    Links: 7
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    r2d2)   Gid: ( 1000/    r2d2)
Access: 2018-04-13 07:43:58.419402046 +0530
Modify: 2018-04-13 07:43:58.411401489 +0530
Change: 2018-04-13 07:43:58.411401489 +0530
 Birth: -